# How to call a button click automatically in xaml win rt application and from where

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

How to call a button click automatically in xaml win rt 
application and from where?

I am using this code:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(button);
IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider; 
invokeProv.Invoke();
```

but from where will it execute?

Answer (score 0):

One example would be when your page with the button is loaded for the first time, then you would simulate the button click in the `Loaded` event:

Page part:

```
public MyPage()
{
    // Constructor
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    Loaded -= OnLoaded;

    ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(button);
    IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
    invokeProv.Invoke();
}
```